# ionic button on list item without ui-sref list item navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I've created an ionic list with a ui-sref so that when an item is clicked on, it navigates to a specific page.  I have also placed a button in the upper right corner of each list item that toggles on and off (sort of like a bookmark).  However, when I click the button to toggle the bookmark, the ui-sref is also triggered, causing an unwanted page navigation.  Is there any way to isolate the button in an ionic list item so when clicked, the list item navigation is not triggered?

Here is my list item code with the button:

```
<ion-item ng-class="{'save': item.save}" collection-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="tab.page({id:item.$id})">
  <button class="icon button top-right" ng-click="item.save = !item.save" ng-class="{'ion-ios-heart button-clear button-assertive':item.save, 'ion-ios-heart-outline  button-clear button-stable':!item.save}"></button>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used ui-sref directive in your ion-item, that make it as a link ( like `<a>` tag ) and then you add your button in between, so of-course when you click on the button, it will do the page navigation.

You need to define your button outside.

```
<ion-item ng-class="{'save': item.save}" collection-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="tab.page({id:item.$id})">      
</ion-item>

<button class="icon button top-right" ng-click="item.save = !item.save" ng-class="{'ion-ios-heart button-clear button-assertive':item.save, 'ion-ios-heart-outline  button-clear button-stable':!item.save}"></button>
```

**Update :**
basically, when you have button inside a link tag, button called first and right after the link triggered. so what you need to do is somehow return false for your ui-sref eveent if button clicked.

Since you are using angularjs, you can do this ( I didn't test it, but it should work, let me know if this worked ) :

1 - add ng-click on your ion-item

```
<ion-item ng-click="isNavigation()" ng-class="{'save': item.save}" collection-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="tab.page({id:item.$id})">
```

2 - change your button ng-click to use a function

```
<button class="icon button top-right" ng-click="myFunctionName(item.save)" ng-class="{'ion-ios-heart button-clear button-assertive':item.save, 'ion-ios-heart-outline  button-clear button-stable':!item.save}"></button>
```

3 - in your controller :

```
$rootScope.isNavigation=true;
$scope.isNavigation=function(){
    if($rootScope.isNavigation)
         return true;
    else
        return false;
}
$scope.myFunctionName(item){
  $rootScope.isNavigation=false;
  return item.save = !item.save;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick!  I understand that if I put the button outside ion-item, then the page navigation will be avoided.  However, I am trying to get my button to show up on each list item in collection-repeat.  Is there a way to link the button to my collection-repeat directive for each list item, but not my ui-sref directive?

Comment: Couldn't quite get this method to do what I wanted, but I found a very simple way to do this: ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"